# What method is used to find the determinant of this $4 \times 4$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

This is a pre-solved example in my book, I don't understand how they solved it. What method is used? 
 
Find the determinant of $A = \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 1 & 0 & 2\\[0.3em]
      -1 & 1 & 1 & 3\\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
       1 & -2 & 0 & 1   
     \end{bmatrix}$

$det(A)=-1\times det \begin{bmatrix}
       -1 & 1 & 3\\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 1 \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 1 \\   
     \end{bmatrix} -2\times det \begin{bmatrix}
       -1 & 1 & 1\\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 0 \\[0.3em]
       1 & -2 & 0 \\   
     \end{bmatrix}$ 
$=-1\times 1+0$
$=-1$

Comment: See the following link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion

Comment: It would be more efficient, by the way, to expand along the third row or third column. Also, there seems to be a typo, the $(3, 3)$ entry of the first $3 \times 3$ matrix should $1$, not $0$.

Comment: This matrix is $4\times 4$, not $5\times 5$ as you wrote in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) is used to calculate the given determinant: we expand along the first row.